# Pipe between processes

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I tried to write a program that takes a string of characters and turns them into Capital Letters. The parent process should take the string and send it to the child process through a pipe. Then the child process should read from the pipe, turn all the letters in Big letters and print it on the console. I don't really understand why my pipe is not working. It might be a problem that the child tries to read the pipe when the parent didn't even write something in it.

Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF 64

/*
Aufgabe: 
Elternprozess: Gibt einen Array mit Klein- und Großbuchstaben mit einer pipe an dem Kindprozess weiter
Kindprozess: Verwanldelt alle Zeichen in Großbuchstaben
*/

int main(void) {
    pid_t pid;

    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);

    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUF);

    switch(pid = fork()) {
        case -1:
            perror("FEHLER BEI FORK\n");
            break;
        case 0: //Kindprozess
            close(fd[1]);
            char c;
            int i = 0;
            while(1) {
                read(fd[0], &c, 1);
                if(c == '\0') {
                    break;
                } else if(c > 64 || c < 123) {
                    buffer[i] = c;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < BUF; i++) {
                if(buffer[i] > 96 && buffer[i] < 123) {
                    buffer[i] -= 32;
                }
            }
            printf("Die Zeichen in Großbuchstaben sind:\n\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < BUF; i++) {
                if(buffer[i] != 0 && buffer[i] != 48) {
                    printf("%c", buffer[i]);
                    printf("   ");
                }
            }
            free(buffer);
            break;
        default: //Elternprozess
            close(fd[0]);
            char string1[] = "a b c d \0";
            memset(buffer, 0, BUF);
            strcpy(buffer, string1);
            int len = strlen(buffer) + 1;
            int n;
            int total = 0;
            while(n < len) {
                n = write(fd[1], buffer, strlen(buffer));
                if(n < 0) {
                    perror("FEHLER BEIM SENDEN\n");
                    break;
                }
                total += n;
            }
            printf("Nachricht gesendet.\n");
            
            free(buffer);
            wait(NULL);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does work? Where do you think the problem is?

Comment: the whole code doesn't work at all.. It doesn't print anything

Comment: `64`, `96`, `123`???  Do you mean `'A' - 1`, `'a' - 1`, and `'z' + 1`?  Don't hard code magic numbers.  If you use `<=` and `>=`, you can omit the decrement/increment.  But you should be using `islower` and `isupper`

Comment: Remember, a debugger is often your best friend. Step through carefully and observe where the flow of execution is going.

Comment: No need for 2 calls to `printf()` with `"%c"` followed by `"   "`, just do `"%c   "`. Add `-Wshadow` to your compile string -- your `i` variable is shadowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with the corrections above, your child process still invokes *Undefined Behavior* writing beyond the end of your string. You iterate `BUF` times when you should only iterate `i` times. Additionally, you are shadowing `i` in the child with:

```c
            int i = 0;
            while(1) {
                read(fd[0], &c, 1);
                if(c == '\0') {
                    break;
                } else if(c > 64 || c < 123) {
                    buffer[i] = c;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < BUF; i++) {
                ...
            }
            printf("Die Zeichen in Großbuchstaben sind:\n\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < BUF; i++) {
                ...
```

You can always catch this problem if you add `-Wshadow` to your compile string for `gcc`. Additionally, you can correct the iteration problem by simply ensuring `buffer` is nul-terminated and then iterating over `buffer[i]` until the nul-character is reached. This simplifies your logic.

Below iterates `for(i = 0; buffer[i]; i++)` to avoid the problem. This is the correct way to iterate over the characters in a nul-terminated string without having to know the length in advance (that's what the nul-terminating character is for)

(edit: - combined loops, simplified with ctype.h macros)

```c
    case 0: //Kindprozess
      close(fd[1]);
      char c;
      int i = 0;
      while(1) {
        read(fd[0], &c, 1);
        if(c == 0) {
          break;
        }
        else if (isalpha ((unsigned char)c)) {        /* is A-Za-z ? */
          buffer[i] = toupper ((unsigned char)c);   /* make uppwer case */
          i++;
        }
      }
      buffer[i] = 0;    /* nul-terminate at i */
      printf("Die Zeichen in Großbuchstaben sind:\n\n");
      for(i = 0; buffer[i]; i++) {
        printf("%*c", i ? 3 : 0, buffer[i]);    /* write 3 spaces except 1st */
      }
      putchar ('\n');
      free(buffer);
      break;
```

Avoid using *MagicNumbers* where possible. Don't use `48` use `'0'` (which makes no sense how you used it). Don't use `>96` when you mean `'a'` or `<123` when you mean `'z'`. Use the literal characters instead -- much more readable.

Also, include `ctype.h` and take advantage of the macros provided for `isalpha()`, `isupper()`, `islower()`, etc.. Much more readable than `>96` and `<123`.

In fact, none of the manual tests of the character value is needed if you use the `ctype.h` macros. In your code, you only include characters sent from the parent if they are *alpha*-characters. You can simply use `isalpha()` for that purpose.

You do not need to test when converting to uppercase if you use the `toupper()` macro -- it will only convert lowercase alpha-characters to upper providing the test internally itself.

It's not a good idea to leave trailing whitespace at the end of the line of output. You can control the 3-spaces between the output characters by writing 3 spaces BEFORE all but the first character output. A simple *ternary* and *field-width* in `printf()` makes that simple, e.g.

```c
        printf("%*c", i ? 3 : 0, buffer[i]);
```

Give this a go along with the correction in the other answer and your program should perform as you expect.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/pipe-fork-uppercase
Nachricht gesendet.
Die Zeichen in Großbuchstaben sind:

A  B  C  D
```

---

**Additional Thoughts**

There are a few other points in your code that are a bit awkward.

- while there is nothing wrong with dynamically allocating buf, for 64-bytes, a simple array declaration using automatic storage on the stack if fine -- and removes the need to track and `free()` the memory when done with it.
- `sizeof(char)` is defined as `1` so it can be omitted in the call to `malloc()` if you do allocate (e.g. `malloc(BUF)` is all that is needed),
- `buffer` is not needed in the parent process. You can simply write the contents of `string1` into the pipe. `buffer` can be declared with automatic storage duration in the child-process only. Good job defining the constant `BUF`,
- when writing output from your program, don't forget to output a `'\n'` after your final output to make your program POSIX compliant. Failure to do so with mess up the next terminal prompt in any OS not named windows. `putchar('\n');` is all that is needed.

Putting it altogether and making the string passed a bit more interesting with `char string1[] = "a b c d*E_F+G-h ";` you would have:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define BUF 64

/*
Aufgabe: 
Elternprozess: Gibt einen Array mit Klein- und Großbuchstaben mit einer pipe an dem Kindprozess weiter
Kindprozess: Verwanldelt alle Zeichen in Großbuchstaben
*/

int main (void) {
  pid_t pid;

  int fd[2];
  pipe (fd);

  switch (pid = fork()) {
    case -1:
      perror ("FEHLER BEI FORK\n");
      break;
    
    case 0: //Kindprozess
      close (fd[1]);
      
      char c, buffer[BUF];
      int i = 0;
      
      while (1) {
        read (fd[0], &c, 1);
        if (c == 0) {
          break;
        }
        else if (isalpha ((unsigned char)c)) {      /* is A-Za-z ? */
          buffer[i] = toupper ((unsigned char)c);   /* make uppwer case */
          i++;
        }
      }
      
      buffer[i] = 0;    /* nul-terminate at i */
      printf ("Die Zeichen in Großbuchstaben sind:\n\n");
      
      for (i = 0; buffer[i]; i++) {
        printf ("%*c", i ? 3 : 0, buffer[i]);   /* write 3 spaces except 1st */
      }
      putchar ('\n');   /* tidy up with newline */
      break;
    
    default: //Elternprozess
      close (fd[0]);
      
      char string1[] = "a b c d*E_F+G-h ";
      int len = strlen (string1) + 1,
          n,
          total = 0;
      
      while (total < len) {
        n = write (fd[1], string1 + total, len - total);
        if (n < 0) {
          perror ("FEHLER BEIM SENDEN\n");
          break;
        }
        total += n;
      }
      printf ("Nachricht gesendet.\n");
      
      wait (NULL);
      break;
  }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/pipe-fork-uppercase
Nachricht gesendet.
Die Zeichen in Großbuchstaben sind:

A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the reader process is reading up until the NUL character, but that will never come, the buffer overflows, and the child dies.

The NUL character is never read because it is never written. Look closely at the write loop, a bit simplified is:

```
int len = strlen(buffer) + 1;
int total = 0;
while(n < len) {
   n = write(fd[1], buffer, strlen(buffer));
   total += n;
}
```

Note that you compute in `len` the number of bytes to be written, including the NUL, but then you write `strlen(buffer)` bytes, *without* counting NUL. Then you add the written bytes to `total` but that variable is not used. So, you are writing copies of the string without the NUL endlessly.

The solution would be something like this:

```
let len = strlen(buffer) + 1;
int total = 0;
while(total < len) {
   n = write(fd[1], buffer + total, len - total);
   if (n < 0) { /*...*/ }
   total += n;
}
```

Comment: @ChanyoungWoo Stack Overflow etiquette would be to mark the answer as accepted if it worked for you by clicking the checkmark below the vote buttons.